# Storing multiple checklist data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php

i have a table which consists of student details like roll no, Name, age. Now i have a table for storing the students who have attended and not attended on the given day and given class. I will be using a form with checklist and names automatically displayed using the student details table, i.e. All the name name and roll no will get displayed with a checkbox to each name. If it checked, it mean the particular student has attended the class and if not checked, then the student didn't attended. These detail should get update in  the attendance table. How to do it using php and MySQL?

Comment: this description is confusing. please post some code or make it at least more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a many to many relation in MySQL.

You have a database table with students, like:

**Table classes**

- Student (primary)
- StudentName
- StudentAge
- (further info)

Create a database table for the Classes with they can attend, like:

**Table classes**

- ClassID (primary)
- ClassName
- ClassDate
- (further info)

Then create a many to many table, like:

**Table attendances**

- ClassID (primary)
- StudentID (primary)

To get the students that attended the class do the following query:

```
<?php
    $lstrQuery = "SELECT `students`.* FROM `students`
                  INNER JOIN `attendances` ON `attendances`.`StudentID` = `students`.`StudentID`
                  AND `attendances`.`ClassID` = {YOUR_CLASS_ID} ";
    $loResult  = mysql_query($lstrQuery);

    while($laRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($loResult))
    {
        // do whatever you like
    }
?>
```

Is this what you had in mind?